# Discolored tomato plant leaves

Tags: leaves, tomatoes

First off, I'm new here so not exactly sure if I'm adding pictures or adding the description correctly. Some of the leaves on my tomato plants look like they're starting to turn yellow. The back of the leaves look fine to me. This is not affecting all of my leaves just a few on every one of my tomato plants. These plants are planted separately in  5 gallon fabric plant pots. They were initially started indoors but put outside about 1 1/2 months ago. I live in NH and the weather has been rainy without much sun, although they are on my balcony with a roof. 
Thank you in advance.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Are the yellow leaves the lowest ones on the plant? If so, you are not feeding enough, and the plant is "recycling" the lower leaves to feed the tip growth. Either that or it is too cold, which inhibits the roots taking up nutrients from the soil. This cause isn't a "disease" but obviously the plants are not growing as strongly as they could be. Use high-potash feed marketed specifically for tomatoes.

Comment: The yellow leaves aren't really the lowest ones, some are the lowest leaves and some are the middle and the top leaves. It seems like the older leaves are the ones turning yellow and the new ones look beautiful. Hopefully the new ones don't turn yellow also. I will try the high-potash feed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Magnesium deficiency to me. But it is hard to say without seeing the whole plant. See this [link](http://vikaspedia.in/agriculture/crop-production/integrated-pest-managment/ipm-for-vegetables/ipm-strategies-for-tomato/nutritional-deficiencies-of-tomato#section-5) for nutrient deficiencies in tomato plants. Epsom salt can help for a quick dose of Mg.

[image]